# Can I update a Resource (Like Autoscalinggroup) in another Region using Node Lambda in a different Region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Am trying to update an AutoScalingGroup in another Region via my Node Lambda deployed in us-east-1.

I've tried setting the region in AWS.AutoScaling() constructor. The CLI COMMAND line argument works fine from an EC2 Instance in us-east-1 by passing --region us-west-2 in the CLI to update the AutoscalingGroup in us-west-2.

But when I attempt the same in Lambda which is in us-east-1, I get a *ValidationError : AutoscalingGroup name not found - null*

```
 var autoscalinggroup = new AWS.AutoScaling({'credentials': credentials, 'region' : 'us-west-2'});
 var params = {
    AutoScalingGroupName : 'converse-kibana-ecs-cluster-QA-Integration-Cluster-Container-1-0-8bint-5-ECSContainerAutoScalingGroup-18F80FECCOLH2',
    MaxSize: 4, 
    MinSize: 2,
    DesiredCapacity: 2
};
autoscalinggroup.updateAutoScalingGroup(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    }
    else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: It should work with some limitations. E.g. CloudWatch in Tokyo gave me an error with not being able to trigger lambda in us-east-1. This is documented and the error is different. I work usually with Python, but I went through docs and your code and cannot see any obvious issue. Note that here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html is described that the region should be set up with Config. Let you try to search for an ASG in us-east-1 with region set to us-west-2 to confirm your hypothesis that region is ignored. Can be an implementation error or really wrong name.

Comment: Are you sure you've passed the correct `AutoScalingGroupName` param? I created an ASG in us-west-2, created a Lambda function in us-east-1 with the code you provided, and invoked the Lambda function. The ASG was updated as expected. However, if I misspelled the name of the ASG, I got the error you posted.

Comment: Interesting.I did pass in the exact ASG name but it didn't work. At this point I have two lambdas in each region that updates their respective ASGs as a workaround